# Connection with Kubectl does not work over LoadBalancer

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubectl

I ran into the following error:

```
2021/04/20 20:02:06 http: proxy error: x509: certificate is valid for 10.233.0.1, 10.0.0.9, 10.0.0.6, 127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.8, (censored public ip), (censored public ip), (censored public ip), not (censored public ip of loadbalancer which points to all 3 master nodes)
```

Occurs when I tried to connect with kubectl to a loadbalancer which directs to one of 3 master nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious that the issue is with the certificate. You need to generate a new apiserver certificate that includes your LoadBalancer IP.

Assuming you used kubeadm to bootstrap your cluster, here is what you should do and see:

```
$ kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --apiserver-advertise-address=<LB_IP>

[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local]
        and IPs [10.96.0.1 <LB_IP>]
```

From [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init-phase/#cmd-phase-certs) about what this command does:

> Generate the certificate for serving the Kubernetes API, and save them
> into apiserver.cert and apiserver.key files.
>
> Default SANs are kubernetes, kubernetes.default,
> kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local,
> 10.96.0.1, 127.0.0.1
>
> If both files already exist, kubeadm skips the generation step and
> existing files will be used.

Notice that kubeadm will skip generation if files already exist. Backup already existing certs, delete the original ones, and run kubeadm to generate a new pair.

---

If you are using some other way to bootstrap k8s, then you are on your own.
You might want to check [how to generate api server certs the hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md#the-kubernetes-api-server-certificate).